# setvisibility VIEW.GONE if textview is empty in a listview using viewholder

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

I have a listview using custom ArrayAdapter using viewholder class pattern. In each row_layout, there are 2 textview A and B. What I want to do is that when either of the textview is empty in that listitems. The view of that particular row should be GONE and don't take up any space.

The following code will result in all textview A being GONE if one of the listitem is having empty textview A, even if some of the listitem have text in textview A. Similarly, if one of the listitem is having empty textiew B, all items in the listview will be GONE.

How do I fix this?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder vh;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_layout, parent, false);

        vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.drugBrandName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drugBrandName);
        vh.drugOtherName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drugOtherName);

        convertView.setTag(vh);

    } else
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    CustomDrugItem di = itemsArrayList.get(position);


    if (di.getDrugBrandName().equals("")) {
        vh.drugBrandName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 


    if (di.getDrugOtherName().equals("")) {
        vh.drugOtherName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView drugBrandName;
    private TextView drugOtherName;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put both states (Visible and Gone) because you are using ViewHolder pattern:

```
    vh.drugOtherName.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(di.getDrugOtherName()) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    vh.drugBrandName.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(di.getDrugBrandName()) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the visibility to VISIBLE if the text is not empty.

```
if (di.getDrugBrandName().equals("")) {
    vh.drugBrandName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    vh.drugBrandName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

if (di.getDrugOtherName().equals("")) {
    vh.drugOtherName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    vh.drugOtherName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```